# Add a Subdomain for the website (domain) deployed on AWS Lightsail instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, plesk, amazon-route53, amazon-lightsail

Add a Subdomain for the website (domain) deployed on AWS Lightsail instance
Currently using:
- AWS Lightsail
- Plesk Control panel
Where can I find the NS for the AWS Lightsail machine? I have to add DNS settings for a Subdomain which is being hosted on another ec2-instance?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can find the NS in Lightsail under Networking Tab --> Create DNS Zone.
by clicking Create DNS Zone you can add your DNS settings